# Which schools are known for graduation level database research?

Tags: database-design

Which schools across the world are best known for research being carried out in database field in recent times?

Answer (score 4):

MIT is the home of [Michael Stonebraker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Stonebraker), probably the leading RDBMS researcher working in academia today. A lot of the research is done in private labs tho', e.g. [CJ Date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date) and [Ted Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd) did much of their early work at IBM.

I am missing a huge amount here as I am only really interested in RDBMS research; there's probably a lot more going on in OODBMS research.